# Variables filled when a checkbox is checked and then adding them together - Getting NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am using jquery.calculation to add up the element on the page.
The first part of my javascript adds these up for the 255 product.

This is my javascript so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".calcTotal").click(
function (){
    // get the sum of the elements
    var studio255_photocopier = $("#studio255_photocopier").sum();
    var sum_checkbox255 = $(".checkbox_sum255:checked").sum();
    var qty255 = $(".qty255").sum();
    var single_total255 = ((studio255_photocopier + sum_checkbox255) * qty255);

    if ($('.sorting_stapling255').is(':checked'))
    {
      var lease_sorting_stapling255 = "25.88";
    };

    if ($('.wake_up_fax255').is(':checked'))
    {
      var lease_wake_up_fax255 = "29.41";
    };

    if ($('.extra_2500_tray255').is(':checked'))
    {
      var lease_extra_2500_tray255 = "24.35";
    };

    var lease_single_total255 = ((lease_extra_2500_tray255 + lease_wake_up_fax255 + extra_2500_tray255) * qty255);

    // Grand total sum
    var grand_total = (single_total255);
    var lease_total = (lease_single_total255);
    // update the total
    $("#grand_total").text("£" + grand_total.toFixed(2));
    $("#lease_total").text("£" + lease_total.toFixed(2));
    }
);

});
```

Also this is the hmtl I'm using:

```
<div class="details options">
                    <h1>Addtional Options functionality</h1><span>choose your upgrades here:</span>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <form id="studio255">
                    <input class="sum255" type="hidden" id="studio255_photocopier" value="1538.24" />
                    <label><input class="checkbox_sum255 sorting_stapling255" type="checkbox" id="studio255_sorting_stapling" name="sorting_stapling255" value="278.3" />
                    Sorter/Stapler</label>
                    <label><input class="checkbox_sum255 wake_up_fax255" type="checkbox" id="studio255_wake_up_fax" name="studio255_wake_up_fax" value="316.25" />
                    Walk Up Fax Kit</label>
                    <label><input class="checkbox_sum255 extra_2500_tray255" type="checkbox" id="studio255_extra_2500_tray" name="studio255_extra_2500_tray" value="261.86" />
                    Extra 2500 large capacity paper tray</label>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div> <!-- details -->

                <div class="details amount">
                    <p>Specify the number of machines you require, the total price will be calculated automatically (displayed at the bottom of this page):</p>
                    <label>Price
                    <input type="number" id="photocopierTotal_255" class="price" name="studio255_price" /></label>
                    <label>Qty
                    <input class="qty255" type="number" id="studio255_quantity" name="studio255_quantity" /></label>
                    <input id="btnClear" type="reset" value="clear" />
                    <input class="calcTotal" type="button" value="calculate" />
                    </form>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div> <!-- details -->

<p>Your total cost is&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="grand_total"></span><br />
        Your total lease cost is&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="lease_total"></span></p>
```

The next bit is where I am getting stuck.
Because they want a lease price as well I thought I would just check when the relevant checkboxes are checked and fill another variable for each and then add them up.
But for some reason it only works if I have any one of the check boxes check but not more than one, if I have more than one check it gives me NaN in the lease total.

The bottom part of the javascript just adds the totals up and then limits then to 2 decimal places.

I'm sure my javascript is a bit crude and maybe I'm doing something obviously wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are "adding" **strings** that you assign earlier:

("12.34" + "56.78") * 9 === "12.3456.78" * 9 "==" NaN * 9 "==" NaN.

Next time, learn the programming language *before* the "framework". jQuery is **not** a language; you don't program *in* jQuery. And there is *no* "javascript": [MDN: JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation about strings. A fundamental basic I should know.

Answer (score 0):

As PointedEars pointed out, you're adding strings together here. The `+` operator works with both strings and numbers. If either side of the equation is a string, the two parts are **concatenated**, if both are numbers, only then are they **added**.

```
var str  = "3.3";
var num1 = 1.1;
var num2 = 1.2;

str + str;   // String: "3.33.3"
str + num1;  // String: "3.31.1"
num1 + num2; // Number: 2.3
```

Then, when you multiply your string, the result is coerced to a number, however, in your case, because your string is something like "3.33.3", that is an invalid number and hence, the result is NaN

```
"3.33.3" * 2 // NaN
```

The answer is to make sure you're working with numbers in the first place. Change all the places you define a numeric string to an actual number:

```
var lease_sorting_stapling255 = 25.88;
```

Or, if the values are coming from your form, you might have to parse them into a number. For this, you can use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` depending if you want decimal places or not.

```
parseFloat("25.88");  // 25.88
parseInt("25.88", 10);  // 25
```

The second argument to parseInt is very important, since that defines the base for the number. Without it, the number could be parsed as octal or hexadecimal.

```
parseInt("007");  // 7
parseInt("008");  // 8
parseInt("009");  // 9
parseInt("010");  // 8 !!
parseInt("010", 10); // 10
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such an indepth answer. I was trying to do it quickly and not thinking about strings and numbers. I just have the vars as numbers now and its fine, so simple.

Comment: @nickf `("33" * 2) === 66 !== NaN`, because `"33"` gets converted to a Number value by the `*` operator (all operands do, unlike e. g. Python where it means repetition).  The problem here is that there are two dots in the concatenated string, and this must convert to the Number value `NaN`.